# Что быстрее? [закрыто]

Tags: php

Что быстрее: переписывать уже существующие значение свойства объекта или создавать переменную и записывать в нее значения в PHP?

Comment: Давайте я не поверю, что Вы уже протестировали и установили, что это является проблемой. Не морочьте себе голову, делайте как понятнее и удобнее.

Comment: Ладно, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: @VlaD, для того чтобы проверить что именно ЭТО является узким местом не всегда надо проводить тесты.

Я задавал вопрос, вы мне так же говорили - а проведены тесты? Т.е. мне для того чтобы удостовериться, что данный способ по сравнению с текущим является "тормозом", надо полностью все переписать и проверить? Несмотря на то, что для этого может понадобится не один месяц?

По данному вопросу - 5 минут на тесты, но в общем - сомнительный подход. То, что ты собираешься проверить уже кто-то проверял и спросить у него - не трудно, но поможет сэкономить кучу времени.

Comment: @BOPOH: Потому что это правильный ответ на любой вопрос об оптимизации. Будет тот или иной код быстрее, зависит от ОС, оптимизатора, нагрузки на память, частоты процессора, производительности памяти, направления ветра и фазы луны.

Гораздо более серьёзный вопрос и нужный вопрос -- не как сделать код _быстрым_, а как сделать его _правильным_. Правильная семантика на два порядка важнее микрооптимизации.

Comment: > Потому что это правильный ответ на любой вопрос об оптимизации.

За исключением очевидных случаев.

Comment: @BOPOH: Пример: если у вас есть такая структура данных: массив пар элементов, и ваша основная операция -- пробежаться по всему массиву и найти элемент, у которого первый компонент равен заданному. В этом случае ваша семантика -- _отображение_ первого компонента на второй, и переход от списка к `std::map` или там `Dictionary<>` даст ускорение в разы. Если же вы потратите время и выясните, что обход массива с преинкрементом счётчика быстрее, чем с постинкрементом, ваш выигрыш будет равен с высокой точностью нулю.

Comment: Ну если речь идет о "микрооптимизации"))) Данный вопрос скорее о ней, но в общем - это не всегда так.

Готов поспорить с тем, что "это правильный ответ на любой вопрос об оптимизации". Повторюсь, для того, чтобы проверить - может понадобиться куча ресурсов.

Иногда лучше спросить у тех, кто уже с этим сталкиваться. И если одни говорят одно, а другие - другое, то тогда уже решать - стоит ли тратить время и проводить тесты.

Че-то кажется, что тема как-то слишком холиварная, дискусии не умещаются в формат хэшкода... А так бы подискутировал, может узнал бы чего-нового))

Comment: @BOPOH: вопрос о том, является ли оптимизация микрооптимизацией, зависит в основном от того, как часто выполняется фрагмент кода. Вы _можете_ позволить себе медленную операцию раз в программе. или допустим раз на нажатие пользователем кнопки в UI (но лучше не в UI-потоке). Вы должны попытаться сэкономить скорость во внутреннем цикле, который исполняется миллионы раз.

Comment: Предлагаю не засорять эту или любую другую тему (в своих все равно буду спорить) данным спором, т.к. "Че-то кажется, что тема как-то слишком холиварная"

Я достаточно хорошо знаком с оптимизацией. Более того, я во многом согласен с вами, но это не значит, что я согласен во всём)

Все-таки своя голова, пусть и дурная))) лучше десятка другой)

Comment: @VladD, @ВОРОН, обратите внимение, что автор не спрашивал **как правильно делать?**, а просто спросил **что в ПХП быстрее?**.

Может быть правильней в первую очередь отвечать на *конкретный* вопрос, а уже потом рассуждать о затратах драгоценного времени разработчика на ту или иную оптимизацию?

Лично я не знаю правильного ответа. Исходя и общих соображений о реализации интерпретаторов и предполагая оптимальность реализации ПХП (в смысле микрооптимизации производительности) думаю, что *переписывать уже существующее значение быстрее*.

Comment: @avp: Ну, у меня нет данных профилирования, тем более, я не уверен, что следующая версия интерпретатора PHP будет работать так же, и соответственно что может быть какой-либо универсальный совет. Однако же мне кажется операция обновления свойства объекта настолько простой и быстрой, что она в принципе не может быть узким местом. Стопроцентной уверенности у меня нет, поэтому комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: @VladD, повторяюсь, но разве автор спрашивал об узких местах?

Comment: Участок кода, который хочет оптимизировать ТС исполняется всего один раз, а не в цикле из 100кк итераций, потому что чтобы в цикле 100кк раз создать новую переменную вместо перезаписи уже существующей надо изрядно постараться.  
Непонятно зачем забивать себе голову такими «оптимизациями». Хотя если поднять сервер на микроволновой печи и запускать PHP на нем, то вероятно придется думать и о таких потерях производительности.

Comment: @avp: нет, не спрашивал, но на его непосредственный вопрос о сравнении скорости у меня нет ответа. Я могу лишь дать совет в комментарии.

Comment: @reinraus, можно предположить вызов функции из цикла и создание в ней локальной переменной (не статической). И, как альтернатива, передача в ф-ю параметром объекта по ссылке. 100500 раз )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Вот тут](http://www.joomlaperformance.com/articles/performance/52_php_programming_tips_43_14_2.html), например, кто-то заморочился кучей тестов 3-4 года назад, и пишет, что работа с уже инициализированной переменной быстрее на 376%, чем с новой. Т.о. чел считает, что на ваш вопрос ответ: быстрее, причём значительно, переписывать свойства существующего объекта, нежели создавать новую переменную.

Comment: Спасибо. Там помимо этого еще есть много интересных деталей.